# read.json only reading the first object in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a multiLine json file, and I am using spark's read.json to read the json, the problem is that it is only reading the first object from that json file

```
val dataFrame = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(path)
dataFrame.rdd.saveAsTextFile("DataFrame")
```

Sample json:

```
{
    "_id" : "589895e123c572923e69f5e7",
    "thing" : "54eb45beb5f1e061454c5bf4",
    "timeline" : [ 
        {
            "reason" : "TRIP_START",
            "timestamp" : "2017-02-06T17:20:18.007+02:00",
            "type" : "TRIP_EVENT",
            "location" : [ 
                11.1174091, 
                69.1174091
            ],
            "endLocation" : [],
            "startLocation" : []
        }, 
            "reason" : "TRIP_END",
            "timestamp" : "2017-02-06T17:25:26.026+02:00",
            "type" : "TRIP_EVENT",
            "location" : [ 
                11.5691428, 
                48.1122443
            ],
            "endLocation" : [],
            "startLocation" : []
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : "589895e123c572923e69f5e8",
    "thing" : "54eb45beb5f1e032241c5bf4",
    "timeline" : [ 
        {
            "reason" : "TRIP_START",
            "timestamp" : "2017-02-06T17:20:18.007+02:00",
            "type" : "TRIP_EVENT",
            "location" : [ 
                11.1174091, 
                50.1174091
            ],
            "endLocation" : [],
            "startLocation" : []
        }, 
            "reason" : "TRIP_END",
            "timestamp" : "2017-02-06T17:25:26.026+02:00",
            "type" : "TRIP_EVENT",
            "location" : [ 
                51.1174091, 
                69.1174091
            ],
            "endLocation" : [],
            "startLocation" : []
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I get only the first entry with id = `589895e123c572923e69f5e7`.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure **multiple** multi line JSON is supported?

> Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object... For a regular multi-line JSON file, set the multiLine option to true

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

Where a "regular JSON file" means the entire file is a singular JSON object / array, however, simply putting `{}` around your data won't work because you need a key for every object, and so you'd need a top level key, maybe say `"objects"`. Similarly, you can try an array, but wrapping with `[]`. Either way, these will only work if every object in that array or object is separated by commas.

tl;dr - the whole file needs to be one valid JSON object when `multiline=true`

You're only getting one object because it parses the first set of brackets, and that's it.

If you have full control over the JSON file, the indented layout is purely for human consumption. Just flatten the objects and let Spark parse it as the API is intended to be used

Comment: @ata If you want to use multiple objects like that, the top level object needs to be an array wrapping all the objects

Comment: Simply putting `{}` around it won't work because you need a key for every object. Similarly,  `[]` will only work if every object in that array is separated by commas. In other words, the whole file needs to be *one valid JSON object*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So is there any way I could read this kind of file with multiple objects?

Comment: You need to flatten the objects. Spark doesn't support the file you currently have

Comment: I comma separated all the objects in the JSON and wrapped inside []. It created an array of JSON objects and I successfully created an RDD out of it. Thank you very much. @cricket_007 can you please post this, I'll accept your answer, it was your solution to wrap it inside brackets, I just noticed to comma separate the objects to make it a list of JSON objects. Thank you so much.

Comment: And what if you dont have full control of the json files. I mean is there a way to read in files with each line a new json object?

Comment: @RudyVerboven As answered, that's the default reader behavior without `multiline=true`. This post was asking if multiple multi-line spanning objects are supported, which it is not

Answer (score 3):

Keep one line and one JsValue in file, remove `.option("multiLine", true)`.
like this:

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```

[image]